# Application hangs when converting base64 string to picturebox image

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When my form is displayed it is fed a base64 string which contains an image, but when I attempt to display this image in a picture box the application hangs and I have to force kill the app. My question is how do I convert the string and then display it in a picture box without it hanging and crashing.

```
public partial class DisplayPic : Form
{
    string base64String;
    public DisplayPic(string img)
    {
        base64String = img;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void DisplayPic_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Convert base 64 string to byte[]
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        // Convert byte[] to Image
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you take a look at the error details (exception type + error message)?

Comment: I don't get any error the app appears to be running but does not accept any input and shows a loading cursor.

Comment: You should use a performance profiler to see the hotspots.

Comment: Alternatively (or in addition) try running in debugger and break when your application appears to be "hanging" to see which code currently is being executed.

Comment: The performance profiler shows that the application uses another 30mb of ram and a small spike in CPU usage, after that the RAM flat lines and there is no other CPU utilization.

Comment: the tag `windows-forms-designer` is for design time problem, if this problem happens at run time, you should remove the tag since it is irrelevant.

Comment: What is the length of the base64 string? is it a extra long one?

Comment: The string is about 100kb to 1mb.

Comment: I think you may have forgotten to wire up the `DisplayPic_Load` so it is never get called.

Comment: It's wired, because in the actions tab of the designer for the form the Load action goes to that function.

Comment: There is nothing seemingly wrong with the code, have you verified that the base64 is actually an image, did you write the bytes to file and test it.

Comment: Yes I have done that and I can verify that the base64 string is an image.

Comment: Try to add a button, and on the button click load the image. Maybe the problem is the code running in the load event... Worth a try.

Comment: You should also follow the debugging hint from Uwe Keim

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I have created a bodge; When the base64 string is converted to bytes I use the `File.WriteAllBytes()` method which saves the file. Once the file is then saved I used the `Image.FromFile()` method which I then used to set the picturebox image.

I know it is a bad way to do it but as I cannot find another way which works this is the option I have gone with.

Thank you for all the help and suggestions.

Comment: I think it is that the memorystream needs to be seek to the beginning, now the position of the stream is at the end. Add this line “ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);” before “pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);”